# Wordpress all inner pages returning 404 after migrating to linux server from windows

Tags: wordpress, iis, bad-request

I have migrated my site : http://www.mahodadhiinfra.com/ recently from windows hosting to linux hosting.
After it hosted and configured homepage running properly but unable to access any other page. i can only access page with a extension.

Ex.
http://www.mahodadhiinfra.com/wp-login.php (Working)
http://www.mahodadhiinfra.com/my-account/lost-password/ (Not working)

Initially I thought it might be a .htaccess issue but my .htaccess seems to be ok.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

After that I tried with permalink change. But nothing worked. Hosting provider confirm that all settings are open what a wordpress required, e.g. AllowOverride ALL etc.

Can anyone please help me to get out of the issue?

Comment: Since you are in Windows hosting, you don't need a `.htaccess` file; IIS doesn't recognize it. Have a look here https://gist.github.com/Toddses/7f3729ddf7c6466bb3dc to see how a web.config file should be to support WordPress.

Comment: They moved from windows TO linux. Maybe check permissions on .htaccess and if mod_rewrite is turned on. I dont really trust hosting providers when they say "everything you need is on".

Comment: make sure that permalink is set to post name and .htaccessfile is not invisible and have enough permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 3 steps can help you:

1. Delete the .htaccess file
2. Login in /wp-admin/
3. Go to Permalink options and click "Save".

Comment: @Brainstorm if your issue is resolve than mark the post as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issue.